# Removing zeros from FrameTicks

Tags: plotting, labeling

I would like to divide values of FrameTicks by factor of 1000 to show KiloUnits instead of Units. How it is possible to do?

Answer (score 7):

May be marked as a duplicate, but there's an easy way to do this that isn't listed in the marked question:

You have a plot:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 40000}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To scale the ticks you just need to have the function you use to scale them `#/1000&` and the inverse of this function `1000 #&`

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 40000}, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{(1000 # &), (#/1000) &}], 
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{(1000 # &), (#/1000) &}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just be careful, these undocumented functions have a manner of breaking - it might not work in the next version when it comes out.